# Python - List of list, compare the item with condition

Tags: python-3.x

I need to compare the elements of a list of list.

Example:

```html
d = [['Test1', '123456', '5000'],
     ['Test2', '123456', '-5000'],
     ['Test3', '123457', '15000'],
     ['Test4', '123458', '10000'],
     ['Test5', '123459', '10000'],
     ['Test6', '123459', '-15000']]
```

I need to output list have same data of column 2 (example: 123456) and have absolute value of column 3 equal (example: |5000| = |-5000|)

The print I need: d = [['Test1', '123456', '5000'],
['Test2', '123456', '-5000']]

Would anyone recommend me the best way to do this?
Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the snippet you need:

```
d = [['Test1', '123456', '5000'],
     ['Test2', '123456', '-5000'],
     ['Test3', '123457', '15000'],
     ['Test4', '123458', '10000'],
     ['Test5', '123459', '10000'],
     ['Test6', '123459', '-15000']]


def get_abs(lst, value):
    return [
        line
        for line in lst
        if abs(int(line[2])) == value
    ]

print(get_abs(d, 5000))
```

It works only with integers. Use float insteed in the if condition if you want.

This is just a comprehension `for` loop with custom condition.